# PostgreSQL materialized view with a "dynamic" timestamp WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a materialized view like this:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <name> AS SELECT <column>, count(<column>)
FROM <table>
WHERE last_updated > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'
GROUP BY <column> ORDER BY <column>
```

It seems that the interval gets evaluated only on materialized view creation, but I'd like to have it re-evaluated on every `REFRESH`, so that I always get the records updated during the last day. Is this possible and how?

Comment: Funny - it works like you want when I try it. After `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` I get a content based on `current_timestamp`.

Comment: Yeah, probably the actual problem was that I got DB corruption. Will test on a fresh server and will report back.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about the false alarm, can I  delete the question somehow?

Comment: There should be a "delete" link underneath your question.

Comment: Yeah, but after I try to do it, it does not allow me to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, seems like materialized views do behave as I want. My problem (empty mat view) was caused by database corruption.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, it shouldn't happen. A`REFRESH` should suffice. Anyhow here is a workaround for the issue:

```
CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT <column>, count(<column>)
FROM <table>
WHERE last_updated > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day'
GROUP BY <column> ORDER BY <column>
```

and then ..

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW bar AS SELECT * FROM foo;
```

Comment: This will not work. 

```ERROR:  Materialized views cannot be defined on regular or late binding views.```