# adding current date to a materialized view in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

we are using Amazon redshift, when we are creating a materialized view with a column to capture current date along with some other columns from a specific table, it is giving an error stating Materialized view cannot contain mutate functions.

Following is the sample code:

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW SAMPLE_TEST AS
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM TABLE_A;

I have also used SYSDATE, GETDATE(), NOW() instead of CURRENT_DATE as well.

but everything is mutable function it seems

it is throwing an error as below:
Amazon Invalid operation: Materialized views cannot contain mutable functions. The given materialized view contains one or more of the following mutable functions: CURRENT_DATE

Comment: Did you find a way to do this. I am also in same situation

Comment: this may work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49009036/1699320